# Trigger is firing twice after update

Tags: apex, trigger

My Trigger is firing twice due to the work flow after update on the account object

Here is my code

**Trigger**

```
trigger updateCreditRating on Account(after  Update) {
AccountTriggerHandler handler = new AccountTriggerHandler();
if(trigger.Isupdate && AccountTriggerHandler.firstRun){
    handler.processRecords(trigger.new, trigger.newMap, trigger.oldMap);
    AccountTriggerHandler.firstRun = false;
}
}
```

**Apex Class**

```
public class AccountTriggerHandler {

public static  boolean firstRun = true;

public void processRecords(List<Account> newList, Map<Id,Account> newMap, Map<Id, Account> oldMap){  

    trailerwizardsComWebservice.ArrayOfSIV_CREDIT_RATING newArray = new trailerwizardsComWebservice.ArrayOfSIV_CREDIT_RATING();
    List<trailerwizardsComWebservice.SIV_CREDIT_RATING> lstSivCreditRating = new List<trailerwizardsComWebservice.SIV_CREDIT_RATING>();
    for(Account myAccount : newList){   

        trailerwizardsComWebservice.SIV_CREDIT_RATING objSivCreditRating = new trailerwizardsComWebservice.SIV_CREDIT_RATING();
        if(myaccount.Credit_Rating__c != '' && oldMap.get(myAccount.id).Credit_Rating__c != myaccount.Credit_Rating__c){

            objSivCreditRating.CUST_CODE = myAccount.Account_Number__c;
            objSivCreditRating.CUST_CREDIT_RATE = myAccount.Credit_Rating__c;
            objSivCreditRating.CUST_DATE_MODIFY = myAccount.LastModifiedDate.format('yyyy-MM-dd');
            objSivCreditRating.CUST_SETCREDIT_BY = myAccount.Credit_Rating_Set_By__c;
            objSivCreditRating.CUST_SETCREDIT_DATE = myAccount.CreatedDate.format('yyyy-MM-dd');
            objSivCreditRating.CUST_SETCREDIT_USER = myAccount.Owner.Name;
            objSivCreditRating.RecordId = '';

        }//End If
        lstSivCreditRating.add(objSivCreditRating);
    }//End For*/
    newArray.SIV_CREDIT_RATING = lstSivCreditRating;
   //postToSFDCCallout(newArray);
    String s = json.serialize(newArray);
    futureCall(s);

}

@future(callout = true)
public static void futureCall(String str){
    trailerwizardsComWebservice.BasicHttpBinding_ISeriesIVServices s = new trailerwizardsComWebservice.BasicHttpBinding_ISeriesIVServices();
    trailerwizardsComWebservice.ArrayOfSIV_CREDIT_RATING newArray = (trailerwizardsComWebservice.ArrayOfSIV_CREDIT_RATING) System.JSON.deserialize(str, trailerwizardsComWebservice.ArrayOfSIV_CREDIT_RATING.class); 
        s.UpdateCreditRating(newArray);


}

}
```

Comment: Its normal that because of workflow rule trigger would get fired twice. But whenever you write code in trigger you should always check for change in before value and new value so that even if trigger fires twice sytem will run your code only once. Currently because of trigger in which area of code you are facing sideeffects?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just simple mistake

```
if(trigger.Isupdate && AccountTriggerHandler.firstRun){
    AccountTriggerHandler.firstRun = false; 
    handler.processRecords(trigger.new, trigger.newMap, trigger.oldMap);

}
```

First set the static variable after that call handler method.

if you first call the handler. Workflow will fire from your handler DML.

So it will fire again trigger but still we are in first time handler.

that's the reason you need to update static variable first.

Comment: Hi Rathan ....Trigger is still firing on insert of the Account record after u r suggested change in the code too

Comment: @rathan it is called twice i am checking in the Apex jobs to conform for sure it is firing twice.

Comment: @rathan...The issue is the trigger is firing on the insert of the record.But it should fire after the update .....right ....Is something i am missing here

Comment: @rathan---->The trigger is firing once only but the thing is it is firing on insert  instead of firing on after  update.

Comment: @rathan --->NO Trigers mine is the only one trigger .But i have work flow rules that updates the account after the insertion

Comment: @Rthan--> I have created the custom settings and created the flag ...How would i use that in my trigger ....I don't have any idea

Comment: can some please help me in this scenario  ?????

Comment: @Rathan :I had to make some changes to the  class .It worked thank you ...@rathan

Comment: Cool. Just curious what type of changes you did do it worked ?

Comment: this solution will not work when you do bulk import where records are more than 200

Answer (score 3):

Yes, It is certain that Triggers would fire again (only again) due to workflow field update association. Please refer 12th Point from Salesforce documentation (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm)

12th Point: **If the record was updated with workflow field updates, fires before update triggers and after update triggers one more time (and only one more time), in addition to standard validations. Custom validation rules, duplicate rules, and escalation rules are not run again**.

Please refer : https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000005328&type=1 knwoledge article for simple solution to overcome this by introducing a Boolean flag.