# Why does this apex trigger update a record twice?

Tags: apex, trigger

I've been trying to troubleshoot this problem for awhile and haven't made much progress, so any tips / tricks / answers that you can provide will be appreciated.

*Description:*

When a Case object leaves a queue (changes ownership from a queue to !queue), increment a field on every case "above" it in the queue.

*Apex:*

```
trigger IncrementSkipCount on Case (after update) {

    String QUEUE_ID = '00H30000000oe6Z';   

    for(Case newCase : Trigger.new){
        Case oldCase = Trigger.oldMap.get(newCase.Id);        

        String oldOwner = oldCase.OwnerId;
        String newOwner = newCase.OwnerId;

        if(oldOwner.contains(QUEUE_ID) && !newOwner.contains(QUEUE_ID)){

            List <Case> casesSkipped = [SELECT Id,Skips__c FROM Case WHERE OwnerId = :QUEUE_ID AND CreatedDate < :newCase.CreatedDate];
            for(Case skippedCase : casesSkipped){

                Decimal skips = skippedCase.Skips__c;
                if(skips == NULL){
                    skips = 0;
                }
                skippedCase.Skips__c = skips + 1;
            }
            update casesSkipped;   
        }
    }
}
```

*Problem:*

What I am finding is that the cases that were created before the case that was taken from the queue (that is, cases that were skipped) are *sometimes* having their skip count go up by 2.  It seems to occur on cases that have not been skipped before, but it is only infrequently reproducible.

Comment: you have a couple of issues to address first -- (1) hardcoded queue  ID (replace with a query based on some name, where name comes from a custom setting or the like; (2) you are doing soql inside a for loop and updates inside a for loop. Read up on bulkification

Comment: Do you use field updates? That can cause triggers to run more than once.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/101812/trigger-is-firing-twice-after-update, but I'm not going to flag this in case that's *not* the case.

Comment: Like corp1645 said, please address hardcoded queueID and make it bulkified. For debugging the issue, check if you have a workflow in the same object which does field update on case, it might cause this.

Comment: You should use `Id` type for new and old values instead of the `contains` method as you may run into case sensitivity issues otherwise.

Comment: @crop1645: Would you be able to explain how a hardcoded queue ID would have an effect on a trigger executing twice?  And, while I am doing updates inside the outer for loop, that is the intention.  When the trigger executes on multiple case records, appropriate cases should be updated multiple times.

Comment: bwalk - hardcoded queryIds will have no relevance to your specific problem - but that technique in conjunction with non bulkification should be addressed in a rewritten trigger/trigger handler before trying to diagnose the issue and present to the community; Lance's suggestion is one way to avoid trigger recursion

Comment: @sfdcfox had it correct.  There was a field update that was causing the trigger to run a second time.  Once that field update had occurred, however, it wouldn't execute a second time, giving the impression of "inconsistently reproducible."  I don't know how to mark a comment as the correct answer here.

Answer (score 2):

As @sfdcfox has already pointed out. [Trigger is firing twice after update](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/101812/trigger-is-firing-twice-after-update) might be the same reason. However, even if it is not - or whatever the root cause is, the solution is the same.

In any util class, define a static variable called inCaseTrigger and initialize it to be false. Then in your code:

```
trigger IncrementSkipCount on Case (after update) {
    if(Util.inCaseTrigger)
        return;

    Util.inCaseTrigger = true;
    //...
```

This will eliminate redundant call to your trigger, whatever the reason is.

Comment: This solution has issues when the #records DML'd in a transaction exceeds 200; better is to have a set of IDs as the static variable